# Native Base: Is it possible to style Select's disabled state?

Tags: react-native, select, native-base

I'm using the Native Base Select component. While Select's data is loading I set isDisabled prop on Select to make the component unpressable. Problem is that by making it disabled I get a different style of Select that I can't change and adjust.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should use Pseudo Props

```
 _disabled={{
          opacity: 30,
        }}
```

Example:

```
<Button
  _hover={{
    _text: { color: "secondary.400" },
  }}
>
```